# Error encountered while defining a function to calculate the Euclidean distance between two points using a struct

Tags: c, math.h

I created a function to calculate the Euclidean distance between two points in C (written in the Codeblocks IDE), however some errors occurred:

```
error: expected ')' before 'p1'|

error: expected expression before ',' token|
```

The errors above occurred inside the function `float Euclidean(struct point p1,struct point p2)`

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct point { float x, y, z; };

int main() {

    struct point p1 = { 2.1, 3.0, 1.2 };
    struct point p2 = { 0.5, 0.5, -0.2 };

    float Euclidean(struct point p1, struct point p2);

    return 1;
}

float Euclidean(struct point p1, struct point p2) {

    float distance;

    distance = (float)sqrt((float)powf((struct point p1[0] - struct point p2[0]), 2)+/n
                           (float)powf((struct point p1[1] - struct point p2[1]), 2)+/n
                           (float)powf((struct point p1[2] - struct point p2[2]), 2));

    return distance;

    printf("the distance between p1 and p2 is %.3f", distance);
};
```

I suspect there is some issue with my typecasting, but I can't figure out why (I'm relatively new to C). Could someone give me some hints?

Comment: When using a struct, just use `p1.x` etc. No need to declare it again. And this struct is not an array. `p1[0]` is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few mistakes in the provied code.
You do not need to add `struct point` annotation to usages of variables. So wherever you need to use variable, you can directly reference them like `Euclidean(p1, p2)`

Another point is you need to declare/define function before using it.

For accessing value within a struct, you use dot notation, not index into it. So you need to use `p1.x` instead of `p1[0]`.

Any statement after return is not run, so your print statement will not be run in the function.

Following is corrected code that compiles and run in GCC 9.3.0:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct point {float x, y, z; };
float Euclidean(struct point p1,struct point p2);

int main()
{
    struct point p1 = {2.1,3.0,1.2};
    struct point p2 = {0.5,0.5,-0.2};

    float distance = Euclidean(p1, p2);
    return 0;
}

float Euclidean(struct point p1,struct point p2){
    float distance;
    distance = (float)sqrt((float)pow((p1.x-p2.x),2)+
                           (float)pow((p1.y-p2.y),2)+
                           (float)pow((p1.z-p2.z),2));
    printf("the distance between p1 and p2 is %.3f\n",distance);
    return distance;
};
```

As said in the other answer, it will be good if you understand the basics of C syntax from some book.

Comment: good answer. Adding a `\n` to `printf()` makes the output nicer :-)

Comment: Added \n in the print statement. Thank you @ingo

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@e_a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70611325/2410359) good answer ...

... rather than use `double` functions for a `float` problem, use `float` functions.  Drop the casting.

```
//float distance;
//distance = (float)sqrt((float)pow((p1.x-p2.x),2)+
//                       (float)pow((p1.y-p2.y),2)+
//                       (float)pow((p1.z-p2.z),2));

float distance = sqrtf(powf((p1.x - p2.x),2) + 
                       powf((p1.y - p2.y),2) +
                       powf((p1.z - p2.z),2));
```

Comment: It is also probably better to use basic multiplication instead of `pow` for squaring the coordinate differences.

Comment: @chqrlie Agreed and not agree.  Good compilers often analyze standard library functions and see code like `powf(x,2)` and then emit efficient code that does not use a true function call, but `x*x` as it is the same functionality - perhaps let the compiler's do the compiler's job.  The above move from `double` to `float` functions imparts a slightly different functionality as `(float)pow((p1.x-p2.x),2)` does a [double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding) versus `powf((p1.x-p2.x),2)`, so the compiler cannot substitute on its own.  As with most FP - many subtleties.

Comment: thanks! My code is able to run, but somehow the result is not printed despite the ```printf``` statement inside the function(above ```return```)...what's going on here?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I removed all the ```\n```  as well as the ```return``` statement in my code, but somehow no value is printed

Comment: Why remove `"\n"`?  Why remove `return`?

Comment: @RandyChen After `distance = .....`, use `printf("Distance %g\n", distance); return distance;`.
`

Comment: that works! thanks

Comment: @RandyChen Either you are not using a C compiler (using a C++ one?) or using a compiler that is 23 years behind the C standard of C99.  What compiler are you using?